# Interchanging integral with real and imaginary operators?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$ \int \sin(3x) \cos(nx) dx \to \Re \int \sin(3x) e^{inx} dx$$

$$ \sin(3x) \to \Im e^{i3x}$$

Hence,

$$ \Re \left( \Im \int e^{i(3+n)x} dx \right) $$

Or,

$$ \Re \left(\Im \frac{e^{i(3+n)}}{i(3+n)} \right) \to \Re \left(\Im \frac{-ie^{i(3+n)}}{(3+n)} \right)$$

Considering,

$$ \Im \frac{-ie^{i(3+n)}}{(3+n)} \to -\frac{\cos(3+n)}{3+n}$$

Hence,

$$ \int \sin(3x) \cos(nx) dx = - \frac{ \cos(3+n)}{3+n}$$

Now this is wrong.. why?
Btw I am using result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139671/why-does-integral-and-the-imaginary-part-commute)

Comment: Note that it is not generally true that $z_2\operatorname{Im}(z_1)=\operatorname{Im}(z_1z_2)$

Comment: But I didn't factor out anything, I simply interchanged the operators and integrals?

Comment: You had $\operatorname{Im}(\sin(3x))e^{inx}=\operatorname{Im}(e^{i(3+n)x})$.  This is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have indeed

$$\sin 3x = \Im e^{i3x}$$ And therefore:

$$(\sin 3x) e^{inx} = (\Im e^{i3x}) e^{inx}$$ and
$$\Re[(\sin 3x) e^{inx}] = \Re[(\Im e^{i3x}) e^{inx}]$$
**which is not equal to**
$$\Re[\Im (e^{i(3+n)x})]$$

In general for two complex numbers

$$\Im(zz^\prime) \neq \Im(z) z^\prime$$

Example

$$\Im( i \cdot i) = 0 \neq  i = \Im(i) \cdot i$$

Comment: You do live up to the name +1

Answer (score 1):

As @MarkViola noted, the problem is nothing to do with calculus, only with how you manipulate complex numbers. To wit, with $w:=\exp3ix,\,z:=\exp inx$ you seem to argue $\Im w\Re z=\Re\Im(wz)$ (which would be $\Im(wz)$, by the way). But$$w=a+ib,\,z=c+id,\,a,\,b,\,c,\,d\in\Bbb R\implies\Im w\Re z=bc,\,\Im(wz)=ad+bc.$$The original problem can be solved without complex numbers using$$2\sin3x\cos nx=\sin[(n+3)x]-\sin[(n-3)x].$$